# How can I store several records into one data record across?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Currently, I have data on my Access table that looks like this:

```
Cat|    Sept 1 2016
Cat|    Sept 2 2016
Cat|    Sept 3 2016
Bobcat| Sept 1 2016
Bobcat| Sept 2 2016
Bobcat| Sept 3 2016
Bobcat| Sept 5 2016
Bobcat| Sept 6 2016
Bobcat| Sept 7 2016
```

What I need the data to display as is:

```
Cat| Sept 1 2016| Sept 2 2016| Sept 3 2016
Bobcat| Sept 1 2016| Sept 2 2016| Sept 3 2016|Null| Sept 5 2016| Sept 6 2016| Sept 7 2016
```

with the Field Names as "Name" "Date1", "Date2", "Date 3"...."Date31". I'm stuck working with this format.

When I try the crosstab query what I get is that the dates Sept 1 2016| Sept 2 2016| Sept 3 2016 become my field names and then it displays a count (or MAX, LAST, MIN, etc). However, I need these dates to appear as data. How do I go about this?

Comment: a quick fix, although it's not mythological is to copy and paste transpose or create it in VBA with the transpose function.

Comment: I considered this method, but this is part of a "report" of sorts that needs to be generated on a monthly basis, and I may not be present to do this.

Comment: Please show more sample data. What happens if there are multiple Categories?

Comment: There you go. It would be sorted/grouped by the name and then I need to display the dates of the previous month, so I have no problems with the field names to go up do Date31, with null date values on dates that do not exist.

Comment: I see. We had an extremely similar question a while ago, but I don't find it. I suggest you browse through the last 4-6 months of http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[ms-access]%20crosstab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can use a crosstab specifying the `MAX()` or `MIN()` which can run on non-numeric data. However, as you can see column names repeat their corresponding value.

```sql
TRANSFORM MAX(t.Date) AS MaxOfUDate
SELECT t.User
FROM TableData t
GROUP BY t.User
PIVOT t.UDate;

-- User     Sept 1 2016 Sept 2 2016 Sept 3 2016 Sept 5 2016 Sept 6 2016 Sept 7 2016
-- Bobcat   Sept 1 2016 Sept 2 2016 Sept 3 2016 Sept 5 2016 Sept 6 2016 Sept 7 2016
-- Cat      Sept 1 2016 Sept 2 2016 Sept 3 2016
```

To get distinct columns names, consider using an in-between query that you then run the cross tab:

```sql
SELECT t.ID, t.User, t.Date,
       'Day' & Day(CDate(t.Date)) As DayCol
FROM TableData t;

-- ID   User    UDate         DayCol
-- 1    Cat     Sept 1 2016   Day1
-- 2    Cat     Sept 2 2016   Day2
-- 3    Cat     Sept 3 2016   Day3
-- 4    Bobcat  Sept 1 2016   Day1
-- 5    Bobcat  Sept 2 2016   Day2
-- 6    Bobcat  Sept 3 2016   Day3
-- 7    Bobcat  Sept 5 2016   Day5
-- 8    Bobcat  Sept 6 2016   Day6
-- 9    Bobcat  Sept 7 2016   Day7

TRANSFORM MAX(q.Date) AS MaxOfUDate
SELECT q.User
FROM TableDataQ q
GROUP BY q.User
PIVOT q.DayCol;

-- User     Day1          Day2          Day3          Day5          Day6          Day7
-- Bobcat   Sept 1 2016   Sept 2 2016   Sept 3 2016   Sept 5 2016   Sept 6 2016   Sept 7 2016
-- Cat      Sept 1 2016   Sept 2 2016   Sept 3 2016
```

Finally, you will notice the cross tab does not include sequential days that no corresponding data covers (e.g., *Day4*). Fortunately, you can specify columns in the `PIVOT...IN()` clause:

```sql
TRANSFORM MAX(q.Date) AS MaxOfUDate
SELECT q.User
FROM TableDataQ q
GROUP BY q.User
PIVOT q.DayCol IN ('Day1', 'Day2', 'Day3', 'Day4', 'Day5', 
                   'Day6', 'Day7', 'Day8', 'Day9', 'Day10',
                   'Day11', 'Day12', 'Day13', 'Day14', 'Day15', 
                   'Day16', 'Day17', 'Day18', 'Day19', 'Day20',
                   'Day21', 'Day22', 'Day23', 'Day24', 'Day25', 
                   'Day26', 'Day27', 'Day28', 'Day29', 'Day30', 'Day31');

-- User     Day1          Day2           Day3           Day4    Day5          Day6        ...
-- Bobcat   Sept 1 2016   Sept 2 2016    Sept 3 2016            Sept 5 2016   Sept 6 2016 ...
-- Cat      Sept 1 2016   Sept 2 2016    Sept 3 2016
```

Comment: Nice answer!  Very thorough.

Comment: Wow, thank you sir! I am going to give this one a try!

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you Parfait!